# iOS TableView cell only being selected only when clicked with 2 fingers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this custom view I make - IT's a DropDown view that allows me to have a drop down functionally.

This is it's .m file:

```
@implementation DropDownView

/**
 The state of the drop down
 */
BOOL isOpen = false;

/**
 The current z position
 */
float currentZPoisition;

/**
 The current table z position
 */
float currentTableZPoisition;

/**
 The drop down view
 */
UIView* dropDown;

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        dropDown =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:VIEW_DROP_DOWN
                                                   owner:self
                                                 options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self setView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setDropDownData:(NSArray*)data {
    if (!data || data.count < 1)
        return;
    _title.text = data[0];
    _currentValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    _dropDownOptions = data;
    [_optionsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}


/**
 Set the view of the drop down load
 */
-(void) setView {
    currentZPoisition = self.layer.zPosition;
    currentTableZPoisition = _optionsTableView.layer.zPosition;
    _title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:133.0/255.0 green:141.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    _optionsTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self setDropDownPosition];
    [dropDown setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_optionsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setViewBorder:_dropDownButton];
    [self addSubview:dropDown];
    [self hideOptions];
}

/**
 Set a view border
 */
-(void)setViewBorder:(UIView*)view {
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:133.0/255.0 green:141.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
}

/**
 Set the position of the drop down in the super view
 */
-(void) setDropDownPosition {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    dropDown.frame = frame;
}


- (IBAction)dropDownClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (isOpen)
        [self hideOptions];
    else
        [self showOptions];
}

/**
 Show the options 
 */
-(void) showOptions {
    float yPosition = _dropDownButton.frame.size.height;
    float width = _dropDownButton.frame.size.width;
    float selfHeight = dropDown.frame.size.height + _optionsTableView.frame.size.height;
    _optionsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPosition, width, _optionsTableView.frame.size.height);
    self.layer.zPosition = 100000;
    _optionsTableView.layer.zPosition = 1000000;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, selfHeight);
    [self addSubview:_optionsTableView];
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:_optionsTableView];
    isOpen = YES;
}

/**
 Hide the options
 */
-(void) hideOptions {
    [_optionsTableView removeFromSuperview];
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, _dropDownButton.frame.size.height);
    self.layer.zPosition = currentZPoisition;
    _optionsTableView.layer.zPosition = currentTableZPoisition;
    [self.superview sendSubviewToBack:self];
    isOpen = NO;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UIColor* grayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:134.0/255.0 green:142.0/255.0 blue:147.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        //set selected background color
        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = grayColor;
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = grayColor;
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[cell.textLabel.font fontWithSize:14]];
    }
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    if (_dropDownOptions)
        cell.textLabel.text = _dropDownOptions[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _dropDownOptions.count;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _title.text = _dropDownOptions[indexPath.row];
    _currentValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
    [self hideOptions];
}

-(void)setSelected:(NSIndexPath *)index
{
    [self tableView:_optionsTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:index];
    _currentValue= [NSNumber numberWithInt: (int)index.row];
}

@end
```

The weird thing is that a cell in the table i'm adding as the drop down options only being clicked if I clicked it with 2 fingers (WHAT ??). The `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not being called otherwise.. I know it's a bit hard to step into someone's code but any ideas ?

This is how it looks when it's closed:
[image]

And open:
[image]

Comment: So you put a UITableView in a UIView subclass, right?

Comment: yes. as a subview. I've added pictures to show how it looks